# complexity of empirical estimator

Tags: distributions, self-study, estimation, computational-statistics, time-complexity

Assume we have i.i.d. data $x_{1}, \dots, x_{n}$ from discrete distribution.

Then, let's us consider empirical estimator:
$$
\hat{p}_{i} = \frac{ \sum_{j=1}^{n}1(x_{j}=i)}{n}
$$

What is the computational complexity of the estimator?

The idea:

First, lets us sort the data. Therefore, it takes $O(n \log n)$.

Second, we compute the size of each cluster (i.e. each interval of sorted data with equal values of $x$) and divide by $n$. It is $O(n)$.

Therefore, the complexity is $O(n \log n)$. The second step can be omitted.

Comment: why are you sorting and where do the clusters come from? Your problem description seems incomplete

Comment: about the sorting: this is the algorithm I propose. Clusters: intervals of sorted data with equal values of $x$.

Comment: Since any reasonable form of output would provide information about the sort order in $O(n)$ time and $O(n)\lt O(n\log n)$ (the minimum time for sorting under the standard computational models), the complexity of any algorithm must be exactly $O(n\log n).$